# Copying SQL Server data into Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a query that works in SQL Server, but won't work in Excel. I'm presuming it has something to do with the create table part but I don't really know.

Is there something simple I need to do?

Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dev.[ExternalPointofDeliverynumber],
    dev.InstallDate
INTO ##TEMPS2
FROM [DOCDPT].[result].[Tbl_Device] AS DEV
WHERE GETDATE() < TimeSliceTo
  AND EquipmentType LIKE ('%S2%') 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    temp.ExternalPointofDeliverynumber,
    temp.installdate,  
    Wo.WorkOrderServiceProduct,
    wo.WOMainUserStatus,
    wo.WorkOrderReasonCategory
FROM
    ##TEMPS2 AS temp
LEFT JOIN
    [DOCDPT].[result].[Tbl_Work_Summary] AS WO ON temp.ExternalPointofDeliverynumber = wo.ExternalPointOfDeliveryNumber 
                                               AND WorkOrderActualVisitDate > '2018-06-01'
                                               AND ((wo.WorkOrderServiceProduct IN ('WARM', 'SMEXCHANGE', 'SMINSTALL') AND WOMainUserStatus = 'COMP')
                                                    OR (wo.WorkOrderServiceProduct IN ('WARM', 'SMEXCHANGE', 'SMINSTALL') AND  WOMainUserStatus = 'PCOM' and WorkOrderReasonCategory ='COMP'))

DROP TABLE ##TEMPS2
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "won't work in Excel"?  Can you post what you're trying to do in Excel?

Comment: Instead of a temp table, why not just use a subquery here? I'm also confused about how are going about running SQL against excel. There's a few ways to do that, but how are you doing that in your example?

Comment: Do you get any errors? What happens when you run this?

Comment: I'm creating a table, so its going in the command text box in properties -> definition. the error message is 'The query didn't run, or the database table could not be opened.' @bishnabob

Comment: Have you tried using a table variable or common table expression instead?

Answer (score 0):

As BishNaboB suggested, replace `##Temp` with a CTE.  I coded this "blind", so you may need to tweak it some:

```
;With cte_temp
As
(
Select Distinct
        DEV.ExternalPointofDeliverynumber
        , DEV.InstallDate
    From DOCDPT.result.Tbl_Device As DEV
    Where
        GetDate() < TimeSliceTo
    And EquipmentType Like ('%S2%')
)


Select Distinct
        temp.ExternalPointofDeliverynumber
        , temp.installdate
        , WO.WorkOrderServiceProduct
        , WO.WOMainUserStatus
        , WO.WorkOrderReasonCategory
    From cte_temp As temp
        Left Join DOCDPT.result.Tbl_Work_Summary As WO
            On temp.ExternalPointofDeliverynumber = WO.ExternalPointOfDeliveryNumber
            And WorkOrderActualVisitDate > '2018-06-01'
            And (
                    (
                        WO.WorkOrderServiceProduct In (
                                                        'WARM', 'SMEXCHANGE', 'SMINSTALL'
                                                    )
                And     WOMainUserStatus = 'COMP'
                    )
            Or      (
                        WO.WorkOrderServiceProduct In (
                                                        'WARM', 'SMEXCHANGE', 'SMINSTALL'
                                                    )
                And     WOMainUserStatus = 'PCOM'
                And     WorkOrderReasonCategory = 'COMP'
                    )
                )
```